# why do I need to use strdup()?

Tags: c, linked-list, copy, singly-linked-list, c-strings

```
typedef struct Node {
    char *word;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

Node* newNode(char *word) {

    Node *n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    n->word = word;
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}
```

In this code (Singly Linked List), If I create many Nodes they all have the name of the last Node and I need to understand why in the `newNode` function I need to use `strdup()` function, when I searched for a solution, in this line of code `n->word = strdup(word);` and create a copy of word in the heap.

If I use `malloc(sizeof(Node));` that means to reserve a place in the heap for this node so every node should be independent why than they share the name of the last Node?

Comment: You don't necessarily need `strdup` in that case. It depends upon what you are passing for `word` when you call `newNode` and if you want that to point to the same string buffer each time or a new one.

Comment: Your question is not clear.. What you mean with "reserve a place on the heap"? And "share"? And how do you call this function with `word`?

Comment: You probably call `newNode` with the buffer every time, i.e. like `char myInput[100]; .....; newNode(myInput)` so all your nodes points to that buffer.

Comment: You need to post how you call `newNode`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I mean that malloc gives that pointer the space that it needs and share means all Nodes that I created have the same word as the last Node

Comment: @ModyElSayed Look at my answer, hopefully you will understand the problem with your code

Comment: @4386427 if that were the case, the argument would have been `char const*` instead of `char*`. No?

Comment: @Ayxan I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: @4386427 I mean if the string  was meant to be copied, it'd be a const pointer as in `char const*` instead of `char*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nodes only contains a pointer and that pointer needs to point to somewhere in memory where your actual word is stored.

Maybe this example will help you understand.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node {
    char *word;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

Node* newNode(char *word) 
{
    Node *n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    n->word = word;
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}

Node* insertNode(Node* head, Node* n) 
{
    n->next = head;
    return n;
}

void printList(Node* head)
{
    while(head)
    {
        printf("%s\n", head->word);
        head = head->next;
    }
}

int main(void) {

    // Step 1: Create a list that "works" due to use of string literals
    Node* head1 = NULL;
    head1 = insertNode(head1, newNode("world"));
    head1 = insertNode(head1, newNode("hello"));
    head1 = insertNode(head1, newNode("test"));
    printList(head1);

    printf("------------------------------------------------\n");

    // Step 2: Create a list that "fails" due to use of a char array
    Node* head2 = NULL;
    char str[20];
    strcpy(str, "test");
    head2 = insertNode(head2, newNode(str));
    strcpy(str, "hello");
    head2 = insertNode(head2, newNode(str));
    strcpy(str, "world");
    head2 = insertNode(head2, newNode(str));
    printList(head2);

    printf("------------------------------------------------\n");

    // Step 3: Change the value that head2 nodes points to
    strcpy(str, "What!!");
    printList(head2);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
test
hello
world
------------------------------------------------
world
world
world
------------------------------------------------
What!!
What!!
What!!
```

Step 1:

The `head1` list works as expected because each node is initialized with a pointer to a string literal which is stored somewhere in memory. Each string literal is stored in different memory. Consequently it's working fine.

Step 2:

The `head2` list doesn't work as you expected. This is because each node is intialized with `str` so all nodes simply points to the `str` array. Consequently, all nodes points to "world", i.e. the last word copied into `str`.

Step 3:

Then a new word, i.e. "What!!" is copied into the `str` array and again every node will now print the contents of `str`, i.e. "What!!".

**Conclusion**:

It all depends on how you call `newNode`.

If you call it with a pointer to some new memory every time, you don't need to copy the word to a new location (or use `strdup`).

But if you reuse a buffer when calling `newNode` you'll need to make a copy to some other memory inside `newNode` (and `strdup` is one way to do that copy)

Answer (score 2):

This line doesn't do what you think:

```
n->word = word
```

You need to use `strdup()` (which by the way is not a standard function as of C18, but might be in C2x) to allocate memory for the string separately. The above line simply copies the address of the string, so `n->word` and `word` point to the same string. This line creates a new string with the same contents:

```
n->word = strdup(word);
```

Or, to be compliant with the standard:

```
n->word = malloc((strlen(word) + 1) * sizeof(char));
strcpy(n->word, word);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because word is a pointer to a string, so when malloc(sizeof(Node)) you are only allocating space for the pointer, but not for the string itself.

That is why you have to initialize n->word separately (note that strdup() does two things for you:  It allocates memory and copies the string into it, then returns the pointer).

Comment: Node contains char *word so why doesn't it create a pointer to that word also?

Comment: That is what the answer says, it allocates memory for JUST the pointer. You need to assign that  pointer the address of some memory allocated for the string

Answer (score 1):

It means that you are passing to the function newNode

```
Node* newNode(char *word) {

    Node *n = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    n->word = word;
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}
```

a pointer to the first character of the same character array the content of which is being changed in the code that calls the function but the address of the array is not changed that is you are using the same array.

You need to make a copy of the string the pointer to which is passed to the function. In this case the function will look more complicated the following way

```
Node* newNode( const char *word ) 
{
    Node *n = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = n != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        n->word = malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 );
        success = n->word != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            strcpy( n->word, word ); 
            n->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            free( n );
            n = NULL;
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

The caller of the function should check whether the obtained pointer is equal to NULL or not equal to NULL.

Here is a simple demonstrative program that shows how you can append new nodes to the list using the function. Pay attention to that the function `strdup` is not a standard C function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Node {
    char *word;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

Node* newNode( const char *word ) 
{
    Node *n = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );
    int success = n != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        n->word = malloc( strlen( word ) + 1 );
        success = n->word != NULL;

        if ( success )
        {
            strcpy( n->word, word ); 
            n->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            free( n );
            n = NULL;
        }
    }

    return n;
}

int append( Node **head, const char *word )
{
    Node *new_node = newNode( word );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        while ( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->next;

        *head = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}

void display( Node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->next )
    {
        printf( "\"%s\" -> ", head->word );
    }

    puts( "null" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    Node *head = NULL;
    const char *word = "Hello";

    append( &head, word );

    word = "World";

    append( &head, word );

    display( head );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
"Hello" -> "World" -> null
```

Comment: This line `head = &( *head )->next;` i know that you have to pass double-pointer to change `Node *head` in main, but I don't understand how this line work.

Comment: @ModyElSayed Now you are passing  a pointer to the pointer next. It is the same as passing a pointer to the pointer to the head node. That is each pointer are passed by reference whether it is the pointer to the head node or the data member next.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, in C++ there is no type "String". String is a bunch of chars that are aligned in an array. It means that string is a pointer. So strdup let you copy the content of the string and do not duplicate the address of that string.